# Samsung Galaxy Ace (Android 2.3.5) Not working correctly

Tags: root-access, samsung

I am new to this, I have no idea what to do, as when I went on a trip, and booted my phone, I realised it wan't supposed to be on at all. However, me being in a hurry I didn't have the time to wait until it booted and shut it down, I just removed the battery (smart thinking, I know). The trouble started. My home button is disabled, I have no lock screen, although enabled, and when I hold the power button, instead of saying "Power Off", "Silent", and "Flight Mode", it only says "Power Off". I have no idea what  I am doing wrong, I rebooted around 20 times, removed battery and sim card, plugged it in, etc. I would be REALLY happy if somebody helped.

PS: The home button works, it's just not enabled, I know this because when the screen is off and the home button is pressed, it turns un. I have no trouble with any buttons, not now, not before. Also I'm rooted for over a year now, it's ALWAYS been smooth.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have a GT-S5830. Looks like this is a software based issue. I recommend you to perform a hard reset.

**Factory reset.**

1. To do that power off the phone. Then press and hold the `home, power` keys few seconds. When you see the Samsung logo release the pressed keys. The phone will be boot into the stock recovery.
2. In recovery navigate to `wipe data/factory reset` option by volume keys and press the power key to select it.
3. Next navigate to the `yes` option using volume keys and choose it by pressing power key.
4. Now your device will be reset. Once it's complicated reboot the Galaxy Ace.

If it's not success, install official firmware.

**Install official Samsung firmware using ODIN.**

1. Download your device firmware from [sammobile](http://www.sammobile.com/firmwares/)  and download the PC Odin [in here](http://d-h.st/E9U).
2. Next power off the phone.
3. Press and hold  Volume down, home and power keys until phone boot into the download mode.
4. Connect the phone to the PC over the USB cable.
5. Make sure that ODIN  "Com Port " area turn to yellow colour.
6. Press "Select Ops" button and choose Cooper.ops file.
7. Under the options make sure that "One Package" checked.
8. Click "One Package" button and choose the firmware .tar.md5 file.
9. To start the flash click on "Start" button. Installation will take few seconds and once it completed phone will be automatically reboot.